Is the join density the density of the vector?
Let $X:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ be random variables with densities $f$ and $g$.
We define
$$F_{X,Y}:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$(x,y)\mapsto P(X\leq x, Y\leq y),$$
and
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=(\partial^2_{xy}F_{X,Y})(x,y).$$
The function $f_{X,Y}$ is the join probability density.
QUESTIONS :

What are the hypothesis needed on $X$ and $Y$ for this construction to make sens ?
Under these assumptions (or stronger ones ?), is $f_{X,Y}$ actually a density for $(X,Y)$ ?

More specifically I want to prove, for every Borel set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ that
$$P\big( (X,Y)\in B \big)=\int_Bf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy.$$
I believe that the main lines of the proof are :

Compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_{X,Y}(x,y)1_B(x,y)dxdy$
Suppose (in a first time) that $B$ is an open square.
Use Fubini
In the inner integral (over $y$), the variable $x$ is fixed, so that the partial derivative $\partial^2_{x,y}$ becomes an usual derivative with respect to $y$.
The inner integral is an integral over a segment (because it is a slice of a square).
Make the integral
Since the open squares form a basis of the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we may be able to induce the "square" result to the "Borel" result.

If these steps are correct, my question becomes : How do we the last step ?

You have not stated any assumptions on $F_{X,Y}$ and your $f_{X,Y}$ is not even defined in general. The definition of joint density in the link is simply wrong.

@geetha290krm I edited the question to add "under what assumptions ?" as part of the question.
